# Printing maps with WMS layers: warning about width & height limits

Tags: qgis, wms, print-composer

Using the mapping I created a template with the necessary elements, but I have a problem, because when I have loaded layers wms and I want to generate the print in pdf format or send direct to the printer, I get this error message "Some servers WMS layer (eg UMN mapserver) has a limit for the WIDTH and HEIGHT parameters.Print layers of these servers can exceed this limit.If this is the case, the WMS layer will not print "

And this happens with any layer of wms service that has loaded. I have tested with versions 2.16 and 2.18 of Qgis. I do not know if there is any specific configuration, as I have reviewed and I find nothing about it.

Comment: Try using tiles

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, putting the data in tiles worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Print composer will try to produce a more detailed/ higher DPI WMS image for your map to prevent it looking blocky when printed. If this pushes your single image WMS request over the size the server can handle you can often solve the issue by switching to a tiled WMS layer in your map.